# Deserialize list set index to object property

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML

```
<ItemsRoot>
     <ItemList>
         <Item>
             <Name>A</Name>
             <ItemList>
                 <Item>
                    <Name>AA</Name>
                 </Item>
                 <Item>
                    <Name>AB</Name>
                 </Item>
             </ItemList>
         </Item>
         <Item>
             <Name>B</Name>
         </Item>
         <Item>
             <Name>C</Name>
         </Item>
     </ItemList>
</ItemsRoot>
```

My Classes are

```
public class Item 
{
   [XmlIgnore()]
   public int ItemIndex {get;set;}

   public string Name {get;set;}

   private Item[] itemsList;
   [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
   [XmlArrayItem("Item", typeof(Item))]
   [XmlArray("ItemList")]
   public Item[] ItemsList
   {
        get
        {
            return itemsList;
        }
        set
        {
            itemsList= value;
        }
   }

}

[XmlRoot("ItemsRoot")]
public class ItemsRoot
{
     private Item[] itemsList;
     [XmlArrayItem("Item", typeof(Item))]
     [XmlArray("ItemList")]
     public Item[] ItemsList
     {
        get
        {
            return itemsList;
        }
        set
        {
            itemsList= value;
        }
     }
}
```

Code for deserializing:

```
public static object XmlDeserialize(string dataXML, Type objectType)
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.LoadXml(dataXML);
    XmlNodeReader xNodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xDoc.DocumentElement);
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType);
    var objectData = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xNodeReader);

    return objectData;
}
```

So what im trying to do is when i deserialize the xml i wanted to populate the ItemIndex variable with the index of the object in the list.

i.e.

> Item object with name A will be index 0
>   Item object with name B will be index 1
>   etc

and then

> Item AA will be index 0 again
>   Item AB will be index 1
>   etc

I am not too concerned about when the ItemIndex is populated. This can happen after the deserialization, I just figured that it was a good spot to be doing this.

Comment: where is the code for deserializing? are you getting any error?

Comment: I have added my deserializing code. There is no error. I just need to populate the ItemIndex variable with its index in the array.

Comment: you want to auto intialize ItemIndex while  deserialization which may not be possible\difficult. you can write method which will traverse through your item lists and intialize item index for each item. Call that method in ItemList Set property in your ItemsRoot class

Comment: Is it easier to be done after deserializing? I am not too bothered when its done.

Comment: `Item AA` should be at the 0th index of the 0th index of the parent list.That is at the postion of `A`. Isn't it?

Comment: @user3322417 XML isself is not well formed. The element type "ItemList" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</ItemList>".

Comment: There is no reason to have the extra tags ItemList.  If you change the XmlArray and XmlArrayItem to XmlElement you can eliminate the extra tag layer.

Answer (score 0):

this should solve the problem -

```
public class ItemsRoot
{
    public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
var s = "<ItemsRoot><ItemList><Item><Name>A</Name><ItemList><Item><Name>AA</Name><ItemList><Item><Name>AAA</Name><ItemList><Item><Name>AAAA</Name><ItemList><Item><Name>AAAAA</Name></Item><Item><Name>ABBBB</Name></Item></ItemList></Item><Item><Name>ABBB</Name></Item></ItemList></Item><Item><Name>ABB</Name></Item></ItemList></Item><Item><Name>AB</Name></Item></ItemList></Item><Item><Name>B</Name></Item></ItemList></ItemsRoot>";

var type = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemsRoot));

var obj = type.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s.ToCharArray())));

var reflectedType = ((ItemsRoot)obj).ItemList.Select((item, index) => new Item
        {
            Index = index,
            ItemList = Find(item),
            Name = item.Name
        });

static List<Item> Find(Item item)
{
        return item.ItemList.Select((j, k) => new Item
    {
     Name = j.Name,
     ItemList = Find(j),//j.ItemList,
     Index = k//Find(item.ItemList, j)
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks amit, but this doesnt solve my problem. I need to populate the ItemIndex property of my object and your answer doesnt do that.

Comment: what do you expect the `ItemIndex` to be for `AA`?

Comment: I have already solved my problem, and i have provided the answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code of how I would've done this.

Here I read the Xml file from disk.

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamXmlDoc(Stream inputStream, string nodeName)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
    {
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
        {
            xmlReader.MoveToContent();

            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        if (xmlReader.Name == nodeName)
                        {
                            var xElement = XElement.ReadFrom(xmlReader) as XElement;

                            if (xElement != null)
                            {
                                yield return xElement;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then, when you call the StreamXmlDoc method, you can populate your model as necessary, as an example below shows.

```
var counter = 0;
    var serializedObjects = XmlHelper.StreamXmlDoc(fs, NodeName);

    foreach (var element in serializedObjects)
    {
        // Convert (Deserialize) the patient XElement to an instance of the DESPatientModel class.
        var item = XmlHelper.XmlDeserialize(element.ToString(), typeof(YourType));
        item.ItemIndex = counter++;
    }
```

Comment: what is `NodeName` is it `ItemList`?

Comment: ItemList.  But your code and Xml might not necessary work out of the box with the example I have given.  If you would like, I can give you more or less a working sample

Comment: it doesnt seem to work. It never loops through my second list with AA and AB

Comment: I never saw that you had an ItemList nested within the List item wihtin a ItemList.

Comment: Once you deserialized the root ItemList, you will have the object in your code and can access the inner ItemList.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this.

in the `Item` Class I added the following:

```
public class Item
{
.
.
.
    //method that will set the ItemIndex to the current index
    public void UpdateIndex(int index)
    {
        this.ItemIndex = index;
        if (this.ItemsList != null)
        {
            this.ItemsList = this.ItemsList.Select((x,index) => x.UpdateIndex(index+1)).ToList();
        }
    }   
}
```

So after deserialization I have the following:

```
ItemsRoot root = (ItemsRoot)CustomSerializer.XmlDeserialize(xmlText, typeof(ItemsRoot));
//now using linq 
root.ItemsList = root.ItemsList.ToList().Select((x,index) =>x.UpdateIndex(index+1))).ToArray();
```

It does the job as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you access `ItemIndex` property only after de-serialization this would work:

```
public class Item 
{
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public int ItemIndex {get;set;}
    ...
    public Item[] ItemsList
    {
       get
       {
          return itemsList;
       }
      set
       {
           itemsList = value;
           if (itemsList != null)
           {
                for(int i = 0; i < itemsList.Length; ++i)
                {
                   itemsList[i].ItemIndex = i;
                }   
           }
       }
   }


 }
```

In more generic case consider adding a Parent property to `Item` class and compute itemIndex on the fly. In this case you would also need to define your own `CollectionType: Collection<Item>` type instead of `Item[]`